# Git merge disable auto apply code changes

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I have a branch called `upgradeRN` and `master`, when i tried to pull `master` into `upgradeRN` there's some conflict files, so i used `git pull --no-ff [remote] master`

let say my `foo.txt` in `upgradeRN` branch has:

```
var version = 'upgradeRN'
```

and my `foo.txt` in `master` branch has:

```
var version = 'masterVersion'
var newStringFromMaster = 'anything'
```

when i run `git pull --no-ff [remote] master`, `foo.txt` should be conflict because of `version` BUT `newStringFromMaster` will auto apply, i want to avoid it

so my expected result is: git would tell me there's a conflict at `var version` and `var newStringFromMaster = 'anything'` will be applied safely

how do i handle git to not auto apply code changes that's not conflicted too?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take pull, in that case it will auto apply the changes where there is no conflict, if just want a comparison between those two branches you have create a PR and verify your changes there, you can't stop auto apply by taking pull.